# XML Schema File

Tags: xml, schema

I would like generate a schema file for the xml file shown below. Basically I would like to turn this into a chart with the headings running across in columns (Item Number, Part Number, etc) and then the rows would be the bomcell col_no from the lower sections. Have tried to get this into Excel using some schema tools to no avail. If someone could point me in the right direction I will likely get the scheme defined.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <transactions>
        <transaction date="1485976336" type="export_bom_spreadsheet" vaultname="PDM_Pro">
            <bom document_id="2113" document_path="\EPDM Demo Files\9011-01765.SLDDRW" id="2133"
                name="9011-01765.SLDDRW: Bill of Materials1" path="\EPDM Demo Files\" type="3">
                <bomheader>
                    <bomcol alignment="center" col_no="0" name="ITEM NO."/>
                    <bomcol alignment="center" col_no="1" name="PART NUMBER"/>
                    <bomcol alignment="center" col_no="2" name="DESCRIPTION"/>
                    <bomcol alignment="center" col_no="3" name="MATERIAL"/>
                    <bomcol alignment="center" col_no="4" name="STOCK SIZE"/>
                    <bomcol alignment="center" col_no="5" name="WEIGHT"/>
                    <bomcol alignment="center" col_no="6" name="VENDOR"/>
                    <bomcol alignment="center" col_no="7" name="Default/QTY."/>
                </bomheader>
                <bomrow document_id="2120" path="\EPDM Demo Files\0040-84339.sldasm" row_no="0">
                    <bomcell col_no="0" value="1"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="1" value="0040-84339"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="2" value="ROTOR, WAFER HEAD MK1"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="3" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="4" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="5" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="6" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="7" value="1"/>
                </bomrow>
                <bomrow document_id="2126" path="\EPDM Demo Files\0020-53948.sldprt" row_no="1">
                    <bomcell col_no="0" value="2"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="1" value="0020-53948"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="2" value="INSULATOR, ECHUCK CONTACT"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="3" value="PEEK"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="4" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="5" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="6" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="7" value="2"/>
                </bomrow>
                <bomrow document_id="2125" path="\EPDM Demo Files\0020-53949.sldprt" row_no="2">
                    <bomcell col_no="0" value="3"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="1" value="0020-53949"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="2" value="HIGH VOLTAGE CONTACT"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="3" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="4" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="5" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="6" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="7" value="2"/>
                </bomrow>
                <bomrow document_id="2115" path="\EPDM Demo Files\9010-01765-1.sldprt" row_no="3">
                    <bomcell col_no="0" value="4"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="1" value="3700-04467"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="2" value="O-RING,  BUNA-N 2-011 70 DURO"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="3" value="-"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="4" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="5" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="6" value="PARKER SEALS"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="7" value="2"/>
                </bomrow>
                <bomrow document_id="2119" path="\EPDM Demo Files\3690-05375.sldprt" row_no="4">
                    <bomcell col_no="0" value="5"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="1" value="3690-05375"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="2" value="SET SCR CUP PT STEEL,  M2.5 X 5"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="3" value="STEEL"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="4" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="5" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="6" value="STOCK DRIVE"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="7" value="2"/>
                </bomrow>
                <bomrow document_id="2117" path="\EPDM Demo Files\3700-02453.sldprt" row_no="5">
                    <bomcell col_no="0" value="6"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="1" value="801655-150"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="2" value="O-RING, BUNA N 2-150 N674-70"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="3" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="4" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="5" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="6" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="7" value="1"/>
                </bomrow>
                <bomrow document_id="2118" path="\EPDM Demo Files\3700-01044.sldprt" row_no="6">
                    <bomcell col_no="0" value="7"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="1" value="3700-01044"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="2" value="O-RING 2-224 BUNA-N"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="3" value="-"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="4" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="5" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="6" value="Parker Seals"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="7" value="2"/>
                </bomrow>
                <bomrow document_id="2116" path="\EPDM Demo Files\3700-98003.sldprt" row_no="7">
                    <bomcell col_no="0" value="8"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="1" value="3700-98003"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="2" value="O-RING, 2-011 BUNA-N"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="3" value="RUBBER"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="4" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="5" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="6" value="Parker Seals"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="7" value="1"/>
                </bomrow>
                <bomrow document_id="2127"
                    path="\EPDM Demo Files\Additional File Folder\0020-53947.sldprt" row_no="8">
                    <bomcell col_no="0" value="9"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="1" value="0020-53947"/>
                    <bomcell col_no="2" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="3" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="4" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="5" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="6" value=""/>
                    <bomcell col_no="7" value="1"/>
                </bomrow>
            </bom>
        </transaction>
    </transactions>
</xml>
```

Would really like this type of output:

```
Item No.  Part Number    Description                Material     etc.
1         0040-84339     Rotor, Wafer Head MK1   
2         0020-93948     Insulator, Echuck Contact
```

Comment: Could you please copy the Xml source, not the rendered output of your browser? Those expand/collapse dashes make the Xml invalid and force people here to tediously cleanse it just to test when creating an answer.

Comment: Writing a schema for this file is not going to make the transformation you want to perform significantly easier. It's a very routine XSLT transformation task, or you could try an off-the-shelf XML-to-CSV conversion tool.

Comment: What would the XSLT look like to tabulate the output? I have not had much luck with XSLT tools out there.